# Stereo vision with OpenCV: PS3 Eye or Logitech C920?

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have read that two PS3 Eye cameras can be  hardware-synchronized to take pictures at the same time, but you need some special drivers to use them and I would need to pay for them because the free version supports just 1 PS3Eye,Is that correct?

Is there any software on OpenCV ready to do stereo with either of the cameras?

The only reason to consider Logitech C920 is thehigher resolution and the wider field of view, but really I  could not find a clear answer of what fps can you get with this camera.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am presently working with two PS3 eye cameras on a similar problem. I actually tried to test [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros?distro=hydro) package. But faced few problems and decided to get the depth map using the [robovision repo](https://github.com/AmmarkoV/RoboVision) and see if sufficient feature points are extracted. The previous link had few `make` errors. It can be fixed by seeing the errors in terminal. Also the camera addresses are fixed to `/dev/video1` and `/dev/video2` .